# $L|_k$ be a finite Galois extension and $M,N$ are subfields containing $k$ such that $[M:k], [N:k]$ are powers of $2$. Is $[MN:k]$ power of $2$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

> Let $L/k$ be a finite Galois extension, and let $M$ and $N$ be subfields containing $k$ such that $[M:k]$ and $[N:k]$ are powers of $2$. Is $[MN:k]$ a power of $2$?

I think this is false, but I have tried with different fields and extensions but didn't get a counterexample. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Say $\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)\cong S_4$. Then you can take subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$, fixing $1$ and $2$, respectively, which correspond to subfields $M$ and $N$; the degree of $M$ and $N$ over $k$ are the indices of $H_1$ and $H_2$ in $\mathrm{Gal}(L/k)$, that is, $4$. The compositum of $M$ and $N$ corresponds to the intersection of $H_1$ and $H_2$, which has order $2$, and hence index $12$.

Comment: That is: under the Galois correspondence, the question is: if two subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ of $G$ have indices in $G$ that are a power of $2$, does $H_1\cap H_2$ have index a power of $2$? And then you can construct counterexamples.

Comment: The statement is true if we also assume at least one of the extensions $M/k$ and $N/k$ is Galois though.